# Clean Column Names in R

Tags: r

I have the following code in R that combines multiple (177) csv files. However in a lot of the files, some column names have spaces and the others have underscores as separators e.g 'Article Number' and 'Article_Number'. I have tried janitor::make_clean_names and make.names etc within the code but I just cannot figure out the correct way to do it.

Any help much appreciated

```
df <- list_of_files %>%
  set_names() %>% 
  map_dfr(
    ~read_csv(.x, col_types = cols(.default = "c", 'TY Stock Value' = "c"), col_names = TRUE,),
    .id = "file_name"  
  )
```

Comment: How many column do you have?

Comment: appprox 19 per file but I want R to read the columns mentioned in the same way

Comment: I think you're looking for "clean_names", or?

Comment: I would also assume that it should work with `janitor::clean_names()`

Comment: I have tried both but get .f missing or another error. The problem is where in my code is the correct place to insert it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add it insight the `map_dfr` function such that each columns get first harmoized before it gets bind together.

```
df <- list_of_files %>%
  set_names() %>%
  map_dfr(~ .x %>%
    read_csv(.,
      col_types = cols(.default = "c", "TY Stock Value" = "c"),
      col_names = TRUE
    )
    %>%
    janitor::clean_names(),
  .id = "file_name"
  )
```

**EDIT**: Step-by-step

There are several ways to tell map which function to use.
The `~` operator creates a formula (or better that I started an anonymous function), i.e. a shortcut for a function. And the argument of the function is `.x` which is in your case one csv-filename. This filename get send via the pipe to the `read_csv` function. There I used the placeholder `.` to tell the function where to put it. Then it reads the data into R and then send it to the `clean_names` function to harmonize names. Finally, you add `.id` from `map_dfr` function. That's all the `purrr` magic :)

Comment: Thank you!!! Worked perfectly! Can I ask how you figured out the correct placement?

Comment: sure, I make an edit.